# How to split a polygon to multiple polygon in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, split, polygon

[image]

I want to make

1. client draw lines
2. slice svg area by client's line
3. when mouse hover sliced area, change background color

I already made 1.. but can't make 2
(and googled about this.. but I can't find appropriate answer.)

How can i split a polygon bt multiple lines?
I would be really glad if you could help me.

[image]

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <svg id="svg" width="300" height="300"></svg>
    </div>

    <script>
        /*off contexmenu*/
        if (document.addEventListener) { // IE >= 9; other browsers
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        } else { // IE < 9
            document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            });
        }
        
        
        var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
        
        let painting = false;
        let startX=0, startY=0;
        
        function startPainting(e){
        
            var x = e.clientX-svg.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var y = e.clientY-svg.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            
            startX = x;
            startY = y;
            painting = true;
            
            /*add line*/
            var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
            newLine.setAttribute('class','line');
            newLine.setAttribute('x1',x);
            newLine.setAttribute('y1',y);
            newLine.setAttribute('x2',x);
            newLine.setAttribute('y2',y);
            newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
            newLine.setAttribute("fill", "black");
            newLine.setAttribute("stroke-width", "3px");
            newLine.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
                if(!painting)
                    e.target.setAttribute("stroke", "green");
            });
            newLine.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
                e.target.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
            });
            newLine.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
                if(!painting)
                    svg.removeChild(e.target);
            });
            svg.append(newLine);
               
        }
        function stopPainting(e){
            if(painting){
                painting = false;
                var i = svg.children.length;
                svg.removeChild(svg.children.item(i-1));
            }
        }
        function onMouseMove(e){
            
            var x = e.clientX-svg.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var y = e.clientY-svg.getBoundingClientRect().top;
           
            if(painting){
                svg.children.item(svg.children.length-1).setAttribute('x2', x);
                svg.children.item(svg.children.length-1).setAttribute('y2', y);
            }
        }
        

        svg.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        svg.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopPainting);
        svg.addEventListener('contextmenu', stopPainting);
        svg.addEventListener('click', startPainting);
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen at the top of that square (where the line doesn't reach the edge)?  Anyway, try typing "line segment polygon intersection" into your favourite search engine.

Comment: Please take a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/giaco/pen/xxGeLeR It may be what you need

Comment: I solved problem!! thanks a lot!!!!!!!